# How to get id in public function beforeSave()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I need to get the last id that was added or modified in beforeSave function() in one model. I try this:

`$this->model->id;`   and `$this->data['model']['short']` but it do not work.

this is correct in cakephp or there is another way to get the id in a model?

Comment: You need the `id` of the model you're currently saving or the one that was last saved?

Comment: yes the model is Link, for example. And I try in beforeSave of model Link  $this->Link->id; but this not work

Comment: Using `$this->data[<ModelName>]['id']` should work. If you put `debug($this->data);` in the function and try to save the script is the value present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this function in the **model** to store the saved id's of the model:

```
function afterSave($created){   
    if($created){
        $this->inserted_ids[] = $this->getInsertID();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then simply get the saved id by using `$this->ModelName->inserted_ids;`